# VLOOKUP not returning correct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Maybe I'm using ´VLOOKUP´ wrong, but I've tried even using a table array. It continuously returns a ´N/A´ or ´#REF´ error back to me.

The spreadsheet is setup with a sheet titled 'Character', ´C6´ is a drop down menu, and ´D6´ is where the ´VLOOKUP´ formula is being written. I have a 2nd sheet listed named, 'Weapon', which is a 13 row sheet with various different text and numerical data information. I'm only trying to pull the numerical data from the 6th row, or column F.

So, this is the function I'm writing:

´=VLOOKUP($C$6,Weapon!$A$2:$M$78,6,0)´

What's odd about this is if I check

´=VLOOKUP($C$6,Weapon!$A$2:$M$78,1,0)´

It will return the text data of the first result in the A column on the 'Weapon' sheet, but it won't return anything else in B,C,D,E,etc. columns if I change that 1 to a 2,3,4,5, etc.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: You said the sheet was named `Weapons`, the plural, but your Excel formula references `Weapon`, in the singular.  Is this a typo?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yea thats a typo. Ill edit the original.

Comment: Generally, `#REF` occurs when the reference doesn't exist (i.e. if you are looking beyond a specified range), and `#N/A` typically occurs when a lookup value cannot be found in a list. Are you certain that the value in `C6` exists somewhere on your `Weapon` sheet in the range `A2:A78`? If not, that would be what is causing the `#N/A` error.

Comment: Yea, so the value that I want it to return is '31'. And it's there.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6kJa4o2.jpg
(The INT field is where I'm writing the Vlookup which is calling the '31' under Intellect in the next image)

https://i.imgur.com/IL0Q3ln.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `VLOOKUPs` to work, it's the ***lookup value*** that is the critical part. And that critical part has to be unique and it has to be *in the first column*. Your table of data on the `Weapon` sheet has "Staff" in Column A.

A quick fix for you is to change your formula to

```
=VLOOKUP($C$6,Weapon!$B$2:$M$78,5,0)
```

Notice the left-most column of the range is now column B and we're getting data from the 5th column.

This assumes that your values in column B are unique and will match up with the values in your drop-down menu in C6 on the Character sheet.